Как вывести сложный объект на график в DevExtreme Angular 17?
Изучаю как работают графики в DevExtreme на Angular 17. Сначала попробовал простой пример графика. Список с телефонами и количеством продажей за некий год. Сам список:
public getPhonesData(): ChartDataItem[] {
    return [
      { name: "iPhone 14", count: 5000 },
      { name: "iPhone 14 Pro", count: 5200 },
      { name: "iPhone SE (2023)", count: 3000 },
      { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23", count: 4500 },
      { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra", count: 4800 },
      { name: "Samsung Galaxy A54", count: 4000 },
      { name: "Google Pixel 7", count: 3200 },
      { name: "Google Pixel 7 Pro", count: 3500 },
      { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13", count: 2700 },
      { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13 Pro", count: 2900 },
      { name: "OnePlus 11", count: 2100 },
      { name: "Sony Xperia 1 V", count: 1800 },
      { name: "Sony Xperia 5 V", count: 1600 },
      { name: "Huawei P60 Pro", count: 1500 },
      { name: "Oppo Find X6", count: 1300 },
      { name: "Realme GT 3", count: 1200 },
      { name: "Motorola Edge 40", count: 1100 },
      { name: "Asus ROG Phone 7", count: 900 },
      { name: "Nokia G22", count: 800 }
    ];
  }

Компонент:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-charts',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,
    DxChartModule],
  templateUrl: './charts.component.html',
  styleUrl: './charts.component.css'
})

export class ChartsComponent {
  constructor(private source: ChartDataSources) {
    this.phones = source.getPhonesData();
  }
  
  protected phones: ChartDataItem[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChartDataSources {
  public getPhonesData(): ChartDataItem[] {
    return [ ... ];
  }
}

html:
<dx-chart [dataSource]="phones">
    <dxi-series [valueField]="'name'" [argumentField]="'count'"></dxi-series>
    <dxo-legend [visible]="true"></dxo-legend>
    <dxo-export [enabled]="true"></dxo-export>
</dx-chart>

По я попробовал вывести более сложный объект, над котором ломаю голову уже пол дня:
  public getPhoneSalesData() : PhoneSalesDataItem[] {
    return [
      {
        country: "USA",
        statistic: [
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 5000 },
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 5001 },
          { name: "iPhone 14 Pro", count: 4500 },
          { name: "iPhone SE (2023)", count: 3000 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23", count: 4800 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra", count: 4200 },
          { name: "Google Pixel 7", count: 3200 },
          { name: "Google Pixel 7 Pro", count: 2800 },
          { name: "OnePlus 11", count: 2100 },
          { name: "Sony Xperia 1 V", count: 1800 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "Germany",
        statistic: [
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 4000 },
          { name: "iPhone 14 Pro", count: 3700 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23", count: 4100 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra", count: 3900 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13", count: 2900 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13 Pro", count: 2600 },
          { name: "Google Pixel 7", count: 2200 },
          { name: "Huawei P60 Pro", count: 1800 },
          { name: "Oppo Find X6", count: 1700 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "India",
        statistic: [
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13", count: 3100 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13 Pro", count: 2900 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy A54", count: 3600 },
          { name: "OnePlus 11", count: 3400 },
          { name: "Realme GT 3", count: 2800 },
          { name: "Oppo Find X5", count: 2500 },
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 3000 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S22", count: 2200 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "China",
        statistic: [
          { name: "Huawei P60 Pro", count: 3400 },
          { name: "Huawei Mate 60", count: 3200 },
          { name: "Oppo Find X6", count: 3100 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13", count: 3300 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13 Pro", count: 3500 },
          { name: "Realme GT 3", count: 2800 },
          { name: "OnePlus 11", count: 2700 },
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 2900 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "Japan",
        statistic: [
          { name: "Sony Xperia 1 V", count: 2500 },
          { name: "Sony Xperia 5 V", count: 2300 },
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 3000 },
          { name: "iPhone 14 Pro", count: 2900 },
          { name: "Google Pixel 7", count: 2000 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23", count: 2200 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13", count: 1800 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "UK",
        statistic: [
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 2800 },
          { name: "iPhone 14 Pro", count: 2600 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23", count: 2300 },
          { name: "Google Pixel 7", count: 1900 },
          { name: "OnePlus 11", count: 2000 },
          { name: "Sony Xperia 1 V", count: 1700 },
          { name: "Realme GT 3", count: 1600 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "France",
        statistic: [
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23", count: 2500 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra", count: 2300 },
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 2400 },
          { name: "iPhone 14 Pro", count: 2200 },
          { name: "Asus ROG Phone 7", count: 2000 },
          { name: "Google Pixel 7", count: 1800 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13", count: 1900 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "Brazil",
        statistic: [
          { name: "Motorola Edge 40", count: 1700 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy A54", count: 1600 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13", count: 1500 },
          { name: "iPhone SE (2023)", count: 1400 },
          { name: "Oppo Find X5", count: 1300 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "UA",
        statistic: [
          { name: "Nokia G22", count: 900 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy A54", count: 1100 },
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 1000 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13", count: 950 },
          { name: "Motorola Edge 40", count: 870 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "South Korea",
        statistic: [
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23", count: 3400 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra", count: 3200 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy Z Fold 4", count: 3000 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy Z Flip 4", count: 2800 },
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 2600 }
        ]
      },
      {
        country: "Italy",
        statistic: [
          { name: "iPhone 14", count: 2100 },
          { name: "Samsung Galaxy S23", count: 1900 },
          { name: "Google Pixel 7", count: 1700 },
          { name: "Xiaomi Mi 13", count: 1600 },
          { name: "Oppo Find X6", count: 1500 }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

В этом случае мы берём ту же статистику, только привязываем её уже к некоторым странам. Суть в том, что бы вывести несколько "линий" на один график разного цвета. Компонент:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-charts',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,
    DxChartModule],
  templateUrl: './charts.component.html',
  styleUrl: './charts.component.css'
})

export class ChartsComponent {
  constructor(private source: ChartDataSources) {
    this.phoneSales = source.getPhoneSalesData();
  }
  
  protected phoneSales: PhoneSalesDataItem[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChartDataSources {
public getPhoneSalesData() : PhoneSalesDataItem[] {
    return [ ... ];
  }
}

Разметка:
<dx-chart [dataSource]="phoneSales">
    <dxi-series *ngFor="let sale of phoneSales" [valueField]="'sale.statistic.name'" [argumentField]="'sale.statistic.count'" [name]="sale.country"></dxi-series>
    
    <dxo-common-axis-settings>
        <dxo-grid [visible]="true"></dxo-grid>
    </dxo-common-axis-settings> 
    <dxo-export [enabled]="true"></dxo-export>
</dx-chart>

В таком виде данные не выводятся на график, а в консоли получаю ошибку:
main.ts:5 W2002 - The Italy series cannot be drawn because the sale.statistic.count data field is missing.

For additional information on this warning message, see: https://js.devexpress.com/error/24_1/W2002

Как правильно вывести такую структуру данных на график?
